# Eval command on discord.py selfbot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am fully aware this is against Discord TOS so no need to tell me! I am looking to make an eval/speak command for my selfbot, I am getting no response from the command. I will post the full code.

```
import discord, os, keep_alive, asyncio, datetime, pytz, requests

from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix='!',
  self_bot=True
)

async def on_ready():
    client.remove_command('help')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("TEST"))

@client.command()
async def imitate(ctx,*, mssg=None):
  if mssg == None:
    await ctx.send('Put the message you need in.')
  else:
    await ctx.send(f'{mssg}')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=False)
```

Comment: You can take a look at the eval command that the creator of the library made, [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/rewrite/cogs/admin.py#L216-L261)

Comment: Make sure to limit the eval to only people you trust because your bot's token can be leaked. Also is there a reason why you have two on_ready functions?